# How SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) works?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[A beginner question, after googling for an answer to this simple question, without success:]

What's being done in the following query (taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx), removed the `DISTINCT` and added a column title):

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ObjName
FROM master.sys.objects;
GO
```

I understand that it's a function, returning an object name for a given object id.

However, The argument for the `SELECT` command (i.e., `OBJECT_NAME(object_id)`) makes me confused, for 2 reasons:

1. I thought that the argument for `SELECT` is (well, usually) a *column name*, while here it is a *value* (within the `name` column of `master.sys.objects`).
2. I don't understand the way `object_id` is used - it is not assigned with a value on the surface of the query; So my only guess is that it's there to be used under the surface in a similiar way to a `foreach` function (i.e., to use C#  terms, `foreach object_id, fill the returned datatable with the datarow`) - but I can't be sure my guess is correct.

So, what is being done with the `SELECT` here?

EDIT:  Following comments, I'll ask it from another angle:

Does `OBJECT_NAME()` refer differently to its argument, so that when it is given a specific id, it returns one value, and when given the name 'object_id` it returns the whole column?

Comment: SELECT list can contain columns, expressions, constants... this is an expression made up of a function that takes one of the table columns as input. You can also do things like `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(4);` - without referencing any table at all. I'm not sure why you think of any individual item in the select list as a "record"... Try changing your query to `SELECT object_id, object_id + 10, OBJECT_NAME(object_id) FROM master.sys.objects` - should make it clearer that object_id is just a name of one of the columns in sys.objects.

Comment: I refer to a 'record' since the description of `OBJECT_NAME()` says "Returns the database object name", and an "object name" is one record in the `name` column. Anyway, I see what your'e saying, but I'm still left with some confusion - I'll edit my question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133182/discussion-on-question-by-heyjude-how-select-object-nameobject-id-works).

Answer (score 5):

1) Yes, you are selecting a column name. You are selecting object_id from the sys.objects table. You are not interacting with the object_name at all from the table.  As Aaron mentioned in his comment, the OBJECT_NAME() is just a function that returns a value/object_id.  For example

```
select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) 
FROM (
select [object_id]
FROM sys.objects) x
```

This query returns the object_name of the objects without you referencing the object name from the objects table in either the select or the subquery.

2)Object_ID is an indentifier for objects in your database. These objects can be tables, triggers, stored procedures, etc.

You can use either a static value or query a value from a table:

```
select OBJECT_NAME(1673317271)

select OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_ID = 1673317271
```

Comment: Please see the edit. Note specifically that calling `OBJECT_NAME` can be done in different ways: passing a specific id (e.g., 4), and - as done here - passing the column name. Is that true?

Comment: @HeyJude You bet.  See example provided

Comment: @HeyJude `OBJECT_NAME()` is just a function that takes a single number as input and returns a single string as output, and it can be used in different ways just like other functions. For example, `SELECT LEN('foo');` and `SELECT name, LEN(name) FROM sys.objects;`

Comment: Well, on my example query - on its surface - `object_id` is not a number, but a string, signifying each number under that column name, and only under the surface it "becomes" a number value, returned for each row. Correct?